# Java developing an app with plugin capabilities

Tags: java, plugins

I'm currently working on an application in Java that contains a core set of functionality, this has to be extended for several different purposes (~10 different purposes) and as such, the best solution that came to mind was the option to add plugins to expand the functionality when needed as opposed to having a different code base for each.

Is the best way of doing this simply creating an interface and extending that in the relevant plugins?

```
public coreCode()
{
    // Core
    doThis();
    doThat();
    // Call plugin code
    plugin.doStuff();
}

// Plugin
public interface PluginInterface()
{
    doStuff();
    ...
}
```

I've looked into JSF etc but due to work limitations (not spcifically authorized etc), they are sadly not a viable option.

**--EDIT--**

It should roughly work like this:

purpose A, B and C require a certain set of functionality and so plugin1 is developed for them, bundled with them and then deployed. purpose D and E require a different set so plugin2 is developed for them, bundled and deployed. etc.

Comment: The different staff you do are decided on run time or static time?

Comment: The different plugins would be deployed separately with each one being deployed on a separate instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For plugins you could create a certain directory where class files implementing a certain interface or extending a certain abstract class are located. Then you can create new instances of these classes and see if they are an instance of the abstract class/interface you want them to be, then make a certain list of them and give users the ability to enable/disable them. If they are enabled you can then cast and execute them.

Comment: That's pretty much the route I was going to go down. Glad to see i'm thinking along the right lines as other people. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to look into [OSGi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osgi) - a dynamic component model where applications are developed and deployed as a set of bundles/plug-ins that can be added, started, stopped and removed remotely without even requiring a reboot of the core/host application.

You can model your application on the Eclipse RCP platform (one the best implementations of OSGi) and create a head-less (without any UI) core RCP application. All other application functionalities would then be developed as plug-ins that can come bundled or added later on to your core RCP application in any combination you like (or your clients may request) even after the application has gone live.

If you're application would have a UI and you like the Eclipse IDE's look and functionalities like "New Project" Wizards, use of Perspectives to change the layout of Views, Workspaces, context-sensitive Help functionality and over-the-network updates through plug-in repositories etc. then it's definitely worth considering. Have a look at this [RCP FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/RCP_FAQ) page to see if this fits your needs.

The only thing that put developers off is that it has a bit of a steep learning curve. The dependencies are always declared declaratively with XMLs and within the code all the components are so de-coupled that you always find yourself interacting with the framework more.

The use of JFace for building UI components puts a lot of stress on the separation between the Model and the View. So, while all of this translates to good application design it doesn't allow rapid application development if one is new to the framework. Most of its other complexities come from the fact that RCP just has so much to offer.

Comment: I did see OSGi, but couldn't really get my head round it at the time. Looking at it again with fresh eyes, it looks as though it would probably be the best bet. Unfortunately, as with JSF, it's not authorized.